# How to select a uniformly distributed subset of a partially dense dataset?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

`P` is an n*d matrix, holding `n` d-dimensional samples. `P` in some areas is several times more dense than others. I want to select a subset of `P` in which distance between any pairs of samples be more than `d0`, and I need it to be spread all over the area. All samples have same priority and there's no need to optimize anything (e.g. covered area or sum of pairwise distances).

Here is a sample code that does so, but it's really slow. I need a more efficient code since I need to call it several times.

```
%% generating sample data
n_4 = 1000; n_2 = n_4*2;n = n_4*4;
x1=[ randn(n_4, 1)*10+30; randn(n_4, 1)*3 + 60];
y1=[ randn(n_4, 1)*5 + 35; randn(n_4, 1)*20 + 80 ];
x2 = rand(n_2, 1)*(max(x1)-min(x1)) + min(x1);
y2 = rand(n_2, 1)*(max(y1)-min(y1)) + min(y1);
P = [x1,y1;x2, y2];
%% eliminating close ones
tic
d0 = 1.5;
D = pdist2(P, P);D(1:n+1:end) = inf;
E = zeros(n, 1); % eliminated ones
for i=1:n-1
    if ~E(i)
        CloseOnes = (D(i,:)<d0) & ((1:n)>i) & (~E');
        E(CloseOnes) = 1;
    end
end
P2 = P(~E, :);
toc
%% plotting samples
subplot(121); scatter(P(:, 1), P(:, 2)); axis equal;
subplot(122); scatter(P2(:, 1), P2(:, 2)); axis equal;
```

[image]

**Edit: How big the subset should be?**

As [j_random_hacker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47984/j-random-hacker) pointed out in comments, one can say that `P(1, :)` is the fastest answer if we don’t define a constraint on the number of selected samples. It delicately shows incoherence of the title! But I think the current title better describes the purpose. So let’s define a constraint: “Try to select `m` samples if it’s possible”. Now with the implicit assumption of `m=n` we can get the biggest possible subset. As I mentioned before a faster method excels the one that finds the optimum answer.

Comment: Just be aware that over half of the time is taken up calculating the distance in `pdist2(P, P)`, so even if you completely optimise the loop, you will only half the total execution time. Interesting question though.

Comment: I don't see any constraint that there should be exactly (or at least) some given number of points in the sample, so: Why not pick any single point at random, and call that your sample?  (To be read as: Think of an appropriate constraint or penalty function, and add it to your question.)

Comment: @zelanix It's highly dependent on the value of `d0`. Smaller `d0`s make the loop slower.

Comment: What I'm saying is that nothing stops "Pick a single point" from being a valid answer to your question *as it is currently stated*.  Since that probably isn't a useful answer to you, you need to update your question by adding some constraints that would forbid it as an answer.

Comment: @j_random_hacker thanks for the notice, I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding closest points over and over suggests a different data structure that is optimized for spatial searches.  I suggest a delaunay triangulation.

The below solution is "approximate" in the sense that it will likely remove more points than strictly necessary.  I'm batching all the computations and removing *all* points in each iteration that contribute to distances that are too long, and in many cases removing one point may remove the edge that appears later in the same iteration.  If this matters, the edge list can be further processed to avoid duplicates, or even to find points to remove that will impact the greatest number of distances.

This is fast.

```
dt = delaunayTriangulation(P(:,1), P(:,2));
d0 = 1.5;

while 1
    edge = edges(dt);  % vertex ids in pairs

    % Lookup the actual locations of each point and reorganize
    pwise = reshape(dt.Points(edge.', :), 2, size(edge,1), 2);
    % Compute length of each edge
    difference = pwise(1,:,:) - pwise(2,:,:);
    edge_lengths = sqrt(difference(1,:,1).^2 + difference(1,:,2).^2);

    % Find edges less than minimum length
    idx = find(edge_lengths < d0);
    if(isempty(idx))
        break;
    end

    % pick first vertex of each too-short edge for deletion
    % This could be smarter to avoid overdeleting
    points_to_delete = unique(edge(idx, 1));

    % remove them.  triangulation auto-updates
    dt.Points(points_to_delete, :) = [];

    % repeat until no edge is too short
end

P2 = dt.Points;
```

Comment: that *is* fast - I like it :) I wasn't aware of delaunay triangulation

Comment: Hmm, I just realized the original request was for N-d datasets.  Triangulation *should* work for a 3d dataset (but I haven't tried it), but it will certainly NOT work for N>3.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify how many points you want to select. This is crucial to the problem.

I don't readily see a way to optimise your method.

Assuming that Euclidean distance is acceptable as a distance measure, the following implementation is much faster when selecting only a small number of points, and faster even when trying to the subset with 'all' valid points (note that finding the maximum possible number of points is hard).

```
%%
figure;
subplot(121); scatter(P(:, 1), P(:, 2)); axis equal;

d0 = 1.5;

m_range = linspace(1, 2000, 100);
m_time = NaN(size(m_range));

for m_i = 1:length(m_range);
    m = m_range(m_i)

    a = tic;
    % Test points in random order.
    r = randperm(n);
    r_i = 1;

    S = false(n, 1); % selected ones
    for i=1:m
        found = false;

        while ~found
            j = r(r_i);
            r_i = r_i + 1;
            if r_i > n
                % We have tried all points. Nothing else can be valid.
                break;
            end
            if sum(S) == 0
                % This is the first point.
                found = true;
            else
                % Get the points already selected
                P_selected = P(S, :);
                % Exclude points >= d0 along either axis - they cannot have
                % a Euclidean distance less than d0.
                P_valid = (abs(P_selected(:, 1) - P(j, 1)) < d0) & (abs(P_selected(:, 2) - P(j, 2)) < d0);
                if sum(P_valid) == 0
                    % There are no points that can be < d0.
                    found = true;
                else
                    % Implement Euclidean distance explicitly rather than
                    % using pdist - this makes a large difference to
                    % timing.
                    found = min(sqrt(sum((P_selected(P_valid, :) - repmat(P(j, :), sum(P_valid), 1)) .^ 2, 2))) >= d0;
                end
            end
        end
        if found
            % We found a valid point - select it.
            S(j) = true;
        else
            % Nothing found, so we must have exhausted all points.
            break;
        end
    end
    P2 = P(S, :);
    m_time(m_i) = toc(a);
    subplot(122); scatter(P2(:, 1), P2(:, 2)); axis equal;
    drawnow;
end
%%
figure
plot(m_range, m_time);
hold on;
plot(m_range([1 end]), ones(2, 1) * original_time);
hold off;
```

where `original_time` is the time taken by your method. This gives the following timings, where the red line is your method, and the blue is mine, with the number of points selected along the x axis. Note that the line flattens when 'all' points meeting the criteria have been selected.

[image]

As you say in your comment, performance is highly dependent on the value of `d0`. In fact, as `d0` is reduced, the method above appears to have even greater improvement in performance (this is for `d0=0.1`):

[image]

Note however that this is also dependent on other factors such as the distribution of your data. This method exploits specific properties of your data set, and reduces the number of expensive calculations by filtering out points where calculating the Euclidean distance is pointless. This works particularly well for selecting fewer points, and it is actually faster for smaller `d0` because there are fewer points in the data set that match the criteria (so there are fewer computations of the Euclidean distance required). The optimal solution for a problem like this will usually be specific to the exact data set used.

Also note that in my code above, manually calculating the Euclidean distance is much faster then calling `pdist`. The flexibility and generality of the Matlab built-ins is often detrimental to performance in simple cases.