# Remove Elements of matrix by eucledian distance

Tags: matlab, matrix, euclidean-distance

I have an `mxn` matrix with `E` nonzero elements. The coordinates of the nonzeros are already available in an `Ex2` vector.

I'd like to check if the minimum Euclidean distance between every pair of nonzero elements is at least `d`. And where this is not the case I'd like to enforce it by zeroing some of the elements (it doesn't matter exactly which elements).

Is there an elegant way of doing this in Matlab?

Comment: When you say you can start with a random element, does that mean that if you have 3 elements `A = (1, 5)`, `B = (1, 7)` and `C = (1,9)` and the minimum distance must be `3` that you don't care whether you keep elements `A and C` or only `A`, only `B`, or only `C`?

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but see this older answer describing delaunay triangulation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36653085/1401351

Comment: I planned to add some weighting to my data later on, so as first approach, it would suffice to start at point `A` remove `B`, and keep `C` as it is above the minimum distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a large number of valid approaches to solving the question as it currently stands. Choosing the right one will depend on the actual nature of your data and the logic you want to use to thin it.

One fairly simple approach is to dilate each nonzero element so that a single "pixel" becomes a circle with radius `d`. Then any pixels too close to each other will be evident by their connected circles.

```
E = rand(100)<0.001;  % dummy boolean data
d = 6;

E_dilated = imdilate(E, strel('disk', d, 0));
E_dilated_labeled = bwlabel(E_dilated);
E_labeled = E_dilated_labeled;
E_labeled(~E) = 0;
```

[image: 3 plots showing output]

Exactly what you do from here is up to you.  If you really can't work out how to finish it off then post in the comments.

Other approaches might use one or more of [`bwmorph`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/morphological-dilation-and-erosion.html), [`bwdist`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html), [`watershed`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/watershed.html), [`delaunay` triangulation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunay.html), and perhaps even [k-means](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) or [agglomerative hierarchical clustering](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/linkage.html), or something else entirely.

Thinking about it, this problem is fairly common in mapping applications, if one thinks of the nonzero entries as markers on a map. Google Maps API has a [long page](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers) about the various options they offer.

---

The plots were produced using the following extra code:

```
subplot(3,1,1);
imshow(ind2rgb(E, gray(2))); axis image
title('E (as Boolean)');
subplot(3,1,2);
im = ind2rgb(E_dilated_labeled, lines(max(E_dilated_labeled(:)+1)));
im(repmat(~E_dilated_labeled, [1,1,3])) = 0;
imshow(im);  axis image;
title('E\_dilated\_labeled');
subplot(3,1,3);
im = ind2rgb(E_labeled, lines(max(E_labeled(:)+1)));
im(repmat(~E_labeled, [1,1,3])) = 0;
imshow(im);  axis image;
title('E\_labeled');
```

Comment: just curious, does the disk structure element represent 'euclidean distance' here? meaning can we equate a geometric circle with a digital one in this case?

Comment: @ElijahRockers - I'm not exactly sure what you mean, the docs for `strel` are online [`here`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel-class.html). As I've written it here, there may well be a problem with +- 0.5 pixels, and indeed you won't be able to get sub sqrt(2) precision with this approach. I suppose the correctness of the answer will  depend on how the OP wants to define sub-pixel distances.

Comment: I guess the precision issue was what I meant to point out, thanks for clarifying my own thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code for you :)
I added a sample of the result as an image[image]

```
% Initialise the constants
d = 0.1;    % Distance Threshold
E = rand(20,2);    % Random Mx2 matrix of x and y coordinates

% Display initial matrix
fig1 = figure;
Ex = E(:,1);
Ey = E(:,2);
scatter(Ex, Ey);

% Repeat each coordinate to form a square matrix
ExRep = repmat(Ex, 1, length(Ex));
EyRep = repmat(Ey, 1, length(Ey));

% Calculate the distance between every set of points
distX = ExRep - ExRep';
distY = EyRep - EyRep';
distAll = sqrt(distX.^2 + distY.^2);

% Display the distance between every set of points
figure;
imagesc(distAll);
colormap('gray')
title('Grid of distance from each points');

% Find the points that are at less then a certain distance
smallDist = distAll < d;
figure;
imagesc(smallDist);
colormap('gray')
title('Grid of points with small distance neighbour');

% Find the points with no near neighbours
numNearNeighbour = (sum(smallDist) - 1);
noNearNeighbour = numNearNeighbour == 0;
E2 = E;
E2(noNearNeighbour, :) = [];


% Display the new matrix
figure(fig1);
hold all;
Ex2 = E2(:,1);
Ey2 = E2(:,2);
scatter(Ex2, Ey2, 'marker', '*');
legend({'all points', ['points with neighbours distance < ' num2str(d)]}, 'location', 'northoutside');
hold off;
```